# Embedded TOMCAT- Implementing RESTful service using Jersey JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, embedded-tomcat-7

I want to use embedded tomcat server in my application. I am trying to create RESTful services using *Jersey JAX-RS*, which when called returns data like bank names, IFSC code of specific bank name etc.

When I am deploying on server (in Eclipse, **Right click on project folder -> run As -> Run on server**, then selecting tomcat server ), it's working fine and URL's are properly getting mapped and I am getting data. But when I am using embedded tomcat server, it's not working and displaying failed to load resource.

I read somewhere that embedded tomcat would require main class, so I implemented main class as follows: **Reference**: http://blog.sortedset.com/embedded-tomcat-jersey/

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, LifecycleException {
    new Main().start();
}

public void start() throws ServletException, LifecycleException,
        MalformedURLException {



    // Define a folder to hold web application contents.
   String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/"; 
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

    // Define port number for the web application
    String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if (webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8080";
    }
    // Bind the port to Tomcat server
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

    // Define a web application context.
     Context context = tomcat.addWebapp("/tomcatembedded", new File(
            webappDirLocation).getAbsolutePath());

    // Define and bind web.xml file location.
     File configFile = new File(webappDirLocation + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
     context.setConfigFile(configFile.toURI().toURL());

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();    
}


}
```

Now *Right Click on Project -> Run as Java Application*,
The url doesn't load data : **localhost:8080/tomcatembedded/webapi/banksList**

What I am missing, is the url wrong or some configuration I am missing?

My directory structure is:
[Eclipse Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eK69.png)

My web.xml is:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>sran.api.ifscLookup.resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!--init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param-->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Where is the code to handle `/banksList`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have made separate class which handles URL endpoints.

Comment: @cricket_007 for bank List:

`@Path("/banksList")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BankNameResource {
 
 private BankNames banknames = new BankNames();
 
 @GET
 public List<String> getBankList(){
  return banknames.getBankNames();
 }`

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional code. Anyways, between that link and your question, I do not see where you have `ResourceLoader extends Application` and load the `ResourceLoader` into the web.xml